# Is there any ASP MVC 3 framework for a restful api?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, frameworks

I've been doing some digging in the web but all i find is either incomplete guides to do it by yourself or guides for the first version of MVC.

Is there any framework for getting a RESTful API or not?

And if no, is there anyway to add a global solution for all models (extending the model or routing of MVC it self), because what i've read involves adding the REST logic to each model/ controller of the application (Which don't look like a good solution to adopt REST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WCF Web API for MVC3](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20started%3a%20Building%20a%20simple%20web%20api)

[Add WebAPI support to MVC3 application](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=788)

Both of these should give you an idea of what's involved.

Are you able to start using MVC4?

Comment: Yes, i thought mvc 3 was the latest one!

Comment: Nope if you start using MVC4, you've got the new WebAPI which is exactly what you want: http://www.asp.net/web-api